# Trouble combining jQuery and .php in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, get

I am trying to make a simple translation site here:http://traductordeinglesaespanol.co/. I created a simple php code that uses get to an external translation api which works fine. Here's the code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['text'])){
  $trans_url ='http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q='.urlencode($_GET['text']).'&langpair=en|es'    ;
  $trans_json = file_get_contents($trans_url); 
  $trans_array = json_decode($trans_json, true);    

  echo $trans_array['responseData']['translatedText'];
 }
?>
```

Here is the simple html form:

```
 <form id="form" method="get" action="tran.php">Enter Text to be Translated below:
 <input name="text" type="text" id="test" />
 <button id="but">Translate</button></form>

 <div class="results"></div>
```

The translation works ok now but I what I would like to do is to grab the tran.php result using jQuery and show it in the "result" class below the form. I am trying to do this by the following:
 I loaded by editing the functions.php file so it loads jQuery and a .js script named tran.js. When I inspect element I see both jQuery and the script being loaded. In the script I put this basic code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#go').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'tran.php',
         success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            }
    });
 });
});
```

and change  action to  to handle the form from this page. (tran.php is in the root directory.) But it isn't working at all. I suspect there is/are some crucial mistakes in the coding but being a complete beginer I cannot find where the mistakes are so any advice/correction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you do AJAX, you don't submit the form... So you are only calling `tran.php` with no parameter... You have to add the text to translate in your get parameter, or in a POST... Did you add log at the beginning of `tran.php` to see if it is reached ? As you check `if(!empty($_GET['text']))`, you are expecting GET elements...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I got your point but not sure how to implement it. Let's say I store the user's input in a "tobetranslated" variable with jQuery. How should then I modify the AJAX call and the tran.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax this way :

```
var to_be_translated = "Hello";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'tran.php',
    data : 'text=' + to_be_translated,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Here I added the "data" label, it says the JS variable `to_be_translated` will be seen as `$_GET['text']` in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Random! You have pointed me to the right direction. Unfortunately there must be an error somewhere. I have managed to make the script store the input inside "to_be_translated" http://pastebin.com/CfVaPn8d but when I place the ajax call as you suggested it does nothing.

Comment: @user5541918 Yeah, I made a typo, you need a comma at the end of each line, not a semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed it to work! There was a small typo:

```
     data : 'text=' + to_be_translated;
```

I replaced the ";" in the end with a comma and now I am getting the result like this: Let's say I input the text name to translate (nobre in spanish!), I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"/> <title>estes</title> </head> nombre
```

So I have to get rid of these headers somehow! Anyway I want to thank you again very much for your help! Gracias!